Efficient data structure to store very large number of file paths with same prefix and ability to perform roll up
I am dealing with very large number of file paths around 10-20 million records. For most parts these filepaths have similar prefixes and only their filename differs but this will not be always true. The filepaths can have different depths too.
For example consider
filesystem:root_dir1/some_dir1/more_dir1/much_more_dir1/file1.txt
filesystem:root_dir1/some_dir1/more_dir1/much_more_dir1/file2.txt
...
filesystem:root_dir1/some_dir1/more_dir1/much_more_dir1/file10.txt

filesystem:root_dir1/some_dir1/more_dir1/much_more_dir2/another_file1.txt
filesystem:root_dir1/some_dir1/more_dir1/much_more_dir2/another_file2.txt
...
filesystem:root_dir1/some_dir1/more_dir1/much_more_dir2/another_file10.txt

filesystem:root_dir1/some_dir2/top_file1.txt
filesystem:root_dir1/some_dir2/top_file2.txt
...
filesystem:root_dir1/some_dir2/top_file10.txt

I have the following needs:

Space efficient: These file paths are obtained from n different machine and sent over wire so it must be space efficient to be a part of payload.
Persistence: I need to persist the data structure in which I will store them and then be able to  later read all of them back and bring in memory.
Combination: Since I receive these filepaths from n different machines on my main server I need to merge/combine all of them together.
Roll up: After there are more than n (say 1000) unique dir/file at a level want to roll up to parent and just drop all paths after that since after n I am not interested in keeping a granular record for space saving.
My main operation on data structure storing this will be add new paths. I do not need to directly check for contains or remove. I do need to iterate over it but do not need any ordering.

For example says n  = 10

filesystem:root_dir1/some_dir1/more_dir1/much_more_dir1/file1.txt
filesystem:root_dir1/some_dir1/more_dir1/much_more_dir1/file2.txt
...
filesystem:root_dir1/some_dir1/more_dir1/much_more_dir1/file11.txt
filesystem:root_dir1/some_dir1/more_dir1/much_more_dir1/file12.txt

In this case as soon as I see filesystem:root_dir1/some_dir1/more_dir1/much_more_dir1/file11.txt I want to drop tracking files under much_more_dir1 and just keep path as
filesystem:root_dir1/some_dir1/more_dir1/much_more_dir1

Similar after some rollups if I have something like this
filesystem:root_dir1/some_dir1/more_dir1/much_more_dir1
filesystem:root_dir1/some_dir1/more_dir1/much_more_dir2
...
filesystem:root_dir1/some_dir1/more_dir1/much_more_dir10
filesystem:root_dir1/some_dir1/more_dir1/much_more_dir11

I want to again rollup to optimize space and only track
filesystem:root_dir1/some_dir1/more_dir1

and so on...
I started with HashSet storing each file paths as an entry. But the space taken by hashset for this was huge so much so that I cannot send it over wire as it was beyond 10 Mb. Max payload size for my RPC call.
I have started looking into Trie and PatriciaTrie for storing this as they seem to be space efficient solution when strings share a common prefix. Also looked into m-ary Tree.
But even with this I might not be able to achieve size limit of 10 mb for say 1 million file paths. So I thought of the roll up approach which is acceptable in my use case to optimize on space.
I am wondering what will be a good data structure which can give me this roll-up functionality and space saving of trie. If there isn't one then how should I go about efficiently building one myself?

A Patricia trie certainly seems like the obvious first choice. It should store 1 million items in 1 mb, as long as the unique trailing portion is no more than 10 characters long on average.

Your payload is limited by 10 Mb and you have 10-20 million records, That means you have a limit of 0.5 - 1 byte per record. That seams to be impossible in a  general case. So you most likely need to either split your data to multiple responses or find a way to reduce the number of records. Can you   ensure that your "rollups" do reduce the number of records enough to have at least a few bytes of storage for each remaining record?

I think you will have to flesh out when and how to roll up - the first node to exceed 1000 unique dir/file will be root, or one of its immediate children if existence of a parent is mandatory.

To clarify the total size of record can be 10-20 million records but they are not reported all together over one RPC. n number of machine report them over multiple RPC calls in parts.
The main server combines them all and this can 10-20 million records. Then I want to use patricia tree and also planning on roll-up.

@greybeard I dont quite follow your comment. Can you please give more details?

your requirements wouldn't typically justify a complicated custom data structure.  Why can't you send over the wire as zip-compressed text, and then process in the main server as a sorted list of strings?

Sure, just use a patricia trie, or really just nested hash maps for simplicity. At each node (representing a directory) keep a counter and just drop the actual contents when it reaches a thousand. In subsequent inserts, only increment the counter.

Will the additions be in any particular order?

Compression cant be done due to technical requirements of larger system. Moreover at some part over it is uncompressed on server I still need to deal with all of it combined which will even be larger. @MattTimmermans

@Bergi Yes I played with a nested hashmap to mimic a tree kinda structure. With the HasMap I dont need to keep the counter. The value is all children (another hashmap). The size of the hashmap act as counter. Once I reach thousand I mark the value with a marker. After I reach the limit I dont care about the counter value.

@RandomS True. All you need to represent a directory node is a hashmap-or-marker. Ideally the marker has the same interface as the hashmap so you can swap out one for the other; though of course how to do that concretely depends on the programming language. However, if you already have that solution, what exactly are you asking for?

If file paths are for a few hierarchical file systems, then I would try splitting each path by the path separator '/' and mapping each portion of the path to a unique integer index then sending the smaller mapping and lists of integers specifying a full path seen.
You might add on top of this your directory grouping if it is still too large.

It seems like a good in-memory structure for this would be a tree implemented as a dictionary of dictionaries. It'd be simple and quick to build and easy to add new paths and remove old ones.
The output format is basically a serialized directory hierarchy, with special characters to separate the ends of paths. For example, if you have two files:
/foo/bar/fooby.txt
/foo/bar/barby.txt

Then your tree would be:
/
  foo
    bar
      fooby.txt
      barby.txt

I think that'll handle 50 million file names just fine, especially if they're in a deeply nested directory hierarchy.
The file format would just serialize what it needs to. So the above would be:
/foo/bar/fooby.txt$barby.txt$

You'll need special characters to mean "go back one directory level" and "start over from the root", but it should be pretty easy to prevent any one path segment from being repeated in the serialized data.
Your needs:

Space efficient. The in-memory representation is not particularly space-efficient. But it's easy to serialize into a space-efficient format that can be sent over the wire and de-serialized. The serialized data is also easily compressed.
Persistence: Easy to store as a compressed text file. Reconstructing the dictionary is a matter of reading the file sequentially and inserting each path as it's decoded.
Combination: Easily done by loading each file and adding the paths to the dictionary structure. Then output the combined dictionary.
Roll up: You can do that when you're building the file, or when outputting the data.
Adding new paths and iterating over the structure are easy. You'll get the files in order (i.e. root, dir1, dir2, etc.) because that's how it's constructed.

Let me clarify that last point. You only have to build the dictionary in memory if you want to modify the data: add or remove items. If you just want to iterate through the files, you can do that easily by reading the file sequentially and constructing the paths as you read the file. You just have to build a simple state machine that interprets the special characters in the data.

special characters to separate the ends of paths, special characters to mean "go back one directory level" and "start over from the root" for an ad-hoc compression scheme trivial to decompress, just prepend the length of the common prefix between the current path and the previous one.

Thank you. I was exploring similar approach right after posting this. I was able to get a very basic thing working but haven't coded all parts like encoding, combining etc. Few questions:

Why did you start the tree with /? I was thinking my first level can just be all the first level parts as key to very first hashmap. So for example if I have /foo1 and foo2. I will have a two distinct tree in the same hash map first key is foo1 and second key is foo2.




Why do you suggest having a "start over from the root"? For the last leaf node in the tree? I can still just use  "go back one directory level" and then see that I have nothing left and just start from root.


For combination. My use case is to combine two in-memory representation of these. So in this case I am wondering what will be the efficient way of merging them. I think I can treat it as merging two tree on same node but wondering if I can make any clever choices given I know the format of data here.



@greybeard can you please clarify your approach and ideally give a visual example. Do you mean do something like:
/foo/bar/fooby.txt$barby.txt$ rather than this I can put as /foo/bar/fooby.txt$9$barby.txt$$ where 9 signify that I should take first 9 letter of the path for next part?

@RandomS You may be right that just a "back one level" is required. Now that I think of it, it's not really a "back one level" but rather an "end of directory". So there's no need for a special "return to root".

@RandomS Starting at root seemed like a reasonable thing to do. If your structure starts at some other directory then just replace / with whatever. And if you'd rather not have that extra root level, it's not going to affect the overall shape of this solution.

@RandomS For combination, you can't just merge the two streams because they aren't in a reliable order. If you want to merge, you either build the dictionary in memory or stream the data to files, concatenate the files, sort them, and then build the data from the sorted file. It's how I'd do it if I didn't need it to be queryable.

@RandomS Remember, my data structure is a tree. It's just implemented with dictionaries (hashmap in java). "Merging two trees on same node" is exactly how the merging process I described works.

@RandomS : just mentioned a serialisation alternative that does not need to inspect each character on iteration/decompression, without details, in the spirit of PackBits. "No separators", number format TBD.

Because there is a lot of repetitions in the paths if they are for real file systems, you might be able to just gzip -9 to max compress the data before sending.
